# Projective module (The lifting property)

Tags: modules, projective-module

I'm looking for an example for a left R-module that doesn't have the lifting property,
From theorems I read, $Z/2Z$ as a $Z$ module should be an example since it' not a direct sum (there isn't a sub-module $K$ of $Z$ such that the direct sum of $Z/2Z$ and $K$ is $Z$).

But I don't understand why $Z/2Z$ doesn't have the lifting property, can someone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $Z/2Z$ had the lifting property. Then in particular the identity map would have a lift, i.e. there would exist a module homomorphism $\varphi: Z/2Z\to Z$ with $\pi\circ\varphi=id$. Show that this yields a contradiction.

Comment: the identity map from Z/2Z to Z is not a homomorphism ...I don't understand what you did

Comment: The identity map $Z/2Z$ to $Z/2Z$ would have to have a lift. The epimorphism is $\pi: Z\to Z/2Z$.